# Specific password recovery

Tags: zip, password-recovery

I have a zip folder which I saved and password protected. I forgot the password but I know that the password is something like : BlueMonday!2012 or bluemonday2012

I know I can brute force the file but it would take too long with that many characters

Is there a software which what use a combination of these characters to find the password?

OS: Windows 8

Comment: "Is there a software which [will] use a combination of these characters" - That *is* brute-forcing! If you meant "a combination of these words/terms", then perhaps a dictionary-based attack would work with a custom dictionary that contains only the words you want.

Comment: Yes, I meant a combination of these letters.
I don't want a custom "word dictionary" , but a custom letters dictionary, is that feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many password recovery programs available (both free and paid) that allow you to specify a custom list of characters to be used for brute-force attacks, [Advanced Archive Password Recovery](http://www.elcomsoft.com/archpr.html) being just one of them (albeit one I have used successfully):

> - Supports all versions of ZIP/PKZip/WinZip, RAR/WinRAR, as well as ARJ/WinARJ, and ACE/WinACE (1.x)
> - Guaranteed recovery of archives in under 1 hour for ZIP archives created with WinZip 8.0 and earlier and containing at least 5 files
> - Supports archives over 4 GB and self-extracting archives
> - Supports strong AES encryption found in WinRAR and the new versions of WinZip
> - Exploits all known vulnerabilities and implementation flaws in the various compression algorithms for faster recovery
> - Speedy known-plaintext attack recovers certain ZIP and ARJ archives in minutes (user must supply at least one unprotected file from that archive)
> - Interrupt and resume operation at any time
> - Supports background operation by utilizing idle CPU cycles only
> - **Dictionary and brute-force attacks with user-defined masks and advanced templates**
> - Highly optimized low-level code for optimum performance

[image: 1]

You can select from predefined character sets or define a custom charset (this is what you want), as also select the word to start from, password mask, password length etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate Zip Cracker can be used to build a custom attack with multiple custom dictionary words. It is expensive though.

Comment: words or letters? OP said 'custom letters dictionary' in his comment at the top... Do you have a link to this?